# What is the mass of the LEGO figurines being launched with spacecraft Juno?

Tags: rocket-science, nasa

What is the mass of the [LEGO figurines](http://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/juno/multimedia/lego20110803.html) being launched with spacecraft [Juno](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juno_%28spacecraft%29)?

How much additional fuel will be needed to get them to Jupiter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the following assumptions:

- [Dimensions](http://snively.blogspot.com/2009/04/lego-minifig-dimensions.html) of a Lego figurine = ~0.59 cubic inches
- The figurines are composed of aluminum, which has a [density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminium) of 0.098 pounds per cubic inch
- The [payload](http://www.spaceandtech.com/spacedata/elvs/atlas5_specs.shtml) weight of the rocket = ~18,000 pounds
- Launch [price](http://www.spaceandtech.com/spacedata/elvs/atlas5_specs.shtml) = ~$110 million

The **weight/mass** of the figurines can be calculated as **0.05782 lbs** or **26.23 grams**:

```
0.59 cubic inches * 0.098 lbs/cubic inch = 0.05782 lbs
```

You can calculate the **launch cost** of the figurines to be roughly **$1,060**.

```
($110,000,000/18,000 lbs) * 0.05782 lbs * 3 figurines = $1,060
```

As for the fuel requirements, I could not locate a source for the amount of fuel required per pound, but it should be fairly easy to come up with the answer if you have that number.

*[[Attribution](http://idle.slashdot.org/comments.pl?sid=2364560&cid=36988626)]*